# What compound can make crunchy biscuits?

Tags: cookies, texture

I want to make Belvita like biscuits. What ingredients do I need to put or not to obtain a crunchy texture (but not a really hard like biscotti). Is "height of the biscuit a important factor ?

Here is my actual recipe, if needed :

```
1 cup of wholeheat flour 
1/2 cup of butter
1/3 cup of sugar
3 eggs 
1 tbsp of honey
```

I've seen on other sites that it can be a good idea to put the butter melted to avoid aeration. Right now they are a little too soft. Thanks for your replies

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unfortunately this is off-topic as you are essentially asking for a recipe. If you search the web for belvita copycat recipes you will find several which might work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I may have worded it badly but I wanted to know what contributed in the crunchy texture. I'll see if I can find something on the web !

Comment: So it's more of a question of what makes a biscuit (cookie) crunchy? It's likely that there are similar questions on this site.

Comment: @GdD : 'mimicry' questions used to be specifically allowed in the FAQ, but they still fall under "[Recipe comprehension, improvement, and repairs](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)".  In this case, Bill is trying to get improve his crunchiness, and has given us his target (similar Belvita biscuits).

Comment: @Joe But Bill has not given us an initial recipe so that we can give specific advice to improve it. If we had said recipe, this would not be a recipe request, it would fit into recipe improvement.

Comment: @Catija : then people should ask for the recipe -- not tell him his question is off-topic and vote to close it.  But people who are familiar with Belvita biscuits (ie, not me), might be able to tell him if it's an ingredient or technique that makes them crunchy.

Comment: Sorry for the mess. As @Joe said, I specified Belvita biscuits because it thought it was the best way to describe what kind of biscuit I wanted to make. Anyway here is my actual recipe, if needed :  
-1 cup of wholeheat flour  
-1/2 cup of butter    
-1/3 cup of sugar  
-3 eggs  
-1 tbsp of honey  
I've seen on other sites that it can be a good idea to put the butter melted to avoid aeration. Right now they are a little too soft. Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 1):

Your comment update suggests that you might be melting the butter ... don't.  Melted butter will make for a softer, chewy cookie..

I don't know if there are episodes of Good Eats available legally online, but there are transcripts of them ... you want episode '[Three Chips for Sister Martha](http://www.goodeatsfanpage.com/season3/cookie/cookietranscript.htm)' in which he discusses how some slight changes to a cookie recipe will make for dramatically different cookies:

> Back to butter. But this time we're going to melt it.
>
> ...
>
> The water from the melted butter will combine during agitation with the higher protein of the bread flour therefore producing gluten ... which is chewy.

You likely want to look at what he did for 'The Thin' variant, which is the only crispy variant in the episode ... but that's not to say that you can't make thick crunchy cookies.  (one of my favorites is LU's Bastogne cookies;  speculaas also comes out crunchy even when fairly thick)  Unfortunately, the recipe from that episode focused on thin (with the side-effect of crispy/crunchy), rather than mentioning what could be done to make it crunchy *without* making it thin.

Comment: Guess I just have to try now.  
Here is an article similar to the Good Eats episode where it discuss change in cookie recipe  : http://sweets.seriouseats.com/2013/12/the-food-lab-the-best-chocolate-chip-cookies.html

Comment: @BillJ. : I had forgotten about that one.  But in skimming it after having read it years ago -- I'd say you also want to drop the honey, as that'll act like corn syrup mentioned (making it stay softer).